# What is the difference between a spin up test and a spin prime test?

Tags: rockets, engines, testing

What is the difference between a spin up test and a spin prime test? And if there is no difference, why not just use the first of those two terms, it being more descriptive?

Comment: Is this related to the Spacex vehicles?

Comment: SPT is a term used exclusively by SpaceX for its rocket engine tests, spin up test just seems to be misleading labels by people talking about Spacex but meaning the same thing as SPT.